# Why does Artifactory attempt to post data to "system/logs/usageartifactory" every 1 minute?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Artifactory OSS and noticed that it attempts to send something like the following every 1 minute:

```
2023-11-03T04:12:06.250Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [4475....08a4] [shipping_service.go:625       ] [main                ] [] - Uploading 13 consumption file/s to 
    artifactory/api/v1/system/logs/usageartifactory/2023-11-03 
    with params map[nodeId:52...b4b productName:artifactory serviceId:01er.....1rha], 

    filelist: [
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T09-21-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T09-36-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T09-51-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T10-06-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T10-21-28.954.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T10-36-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T10-51-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T11-06-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-02T11-21-28.955.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-03T03-54-53.276.log 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-consumption-usage-2023-11-03T03-54-53.276.log.gz 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-traffic-2023-11-02T04-06-28.954.log 
        /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/metadata/usage/archived/metadata-traffic-2023-11-02T04-06-28.954.log.gz
        ] [shipping_service]


2023-11-03T04:10:06.282Z 35[jfob ] [ERROR] [4475...08a4] [artifactory_client.go:131     ] [main                ] [] - 
    Upload file to Artifactory API returned: 404 {
        "errors" : [ {
            "status" : 404,
            "message" : "Not Found"
        } ]
    } [artifactory_client]
```

Could you please advise on how to handle these messages? What are they? Is it possible to stop them from being sent?